# Gantt charts with ranged estimates?

Tags: estimation, reporting, gantt

I'd like to create Gantt charts with ranged estimates (for reporting to non-technical execs) but don't want to use a web service (LiquidPlanner). How can I get Gantt charts with range estimates?

Answer (score 1):

I personally will use Excel Gantt template provided by Vertex42 or any other templates available out there (use your best tool google it): [enter link description here](http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/excel-gantt-chart.html), and will adjust the range estimates as the work progress or stalls and share it  with executive team using a file sharing provider (one single source of the truth) in order for them to get always the up-to-date version.